# Is there any difference between these two functions in F#?

Tags: function, lambda, f#, closures

In F# is there any difference between writing a function like this...

`let add x y = x + y`

Or this...

`let add = fun x y -> x + y`

When I look at the IL it seems they generate exactly the same type of IL. And they certainly "seem" to do the same thing but conceptually I feel they are different, the first being a function declaration and the second being a value declaration with the "value" being a function.

Furthermore, if we would make a slightly more elaborate example..

This...

```
let add x = 
    let rnd = System.Random()
    let rnd = rnd.Next(100)
    x + rnd
```

... Compared to this

```
let add = 
    let rnd = System.Random()
    let rnd = rnd.Next(100) 
    (fun x -> x + rnd)
```

These examples follow the same principles as the previous two but these two will work wildly different from eachother..

Comment: System.Random constitutes a side-effect, therefore the difference you see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In F#, every expression you bind with the `let` keyword is a *value*, including functions; functions are values, too.

Thus, binding the function `fun x y -> x + y` to `add` is one way to create a function value, but a more idiomatic way is to use the syntax `let add x y = x + y`.

They are, however, completely equivalent.

The syntax using the `fun` keyword is mostly used to compose functions into higher-order functions, like when you want to filter on an in-line expression; e.g.:

```
numbers |> List.filter (fun i -> i % 2 = 0)
```

You can, however, also use functions created like this as return values, as in your example.

As you state, the two more complex examples aren't equivalent, but the following would be equivalent with the first, more idiomatic, function:

```
let add = 
    fun x ->
        let rnd = System.Random()
        let rnd = rnd.Next(100)
        x + rnd
```

This isn't idiomatic, so I'd most often write it as in the OP:

```
let add x = 
    let rnd = System.Random()
    let rnd = rnd.Next(100)
    x + rnd
```

While they are equivalent, the idiomatic version is shorter, so, one supposes, more readable.